# SAS %QUOTE vs %BQUOTE

Tags: sas, quoting

I read somewhere (I can't find where anymore ...) that the SAS %bquote function solves some minor problems in the %quote function and that it is more robust. Is it true? What were the problems with %quote?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What code have you tried to test this?

Comment: The first somewhere to check is the documentation.  Try ["Summary of Macro Quoting Functions and the Characters That They Mask"](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=p0pwrvnlcooi3tn0z3g1755ebcng.htm&locale=en)

Comment: Basically always use %bquote :) I haven't found any use for %quote over %bquote yet.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, %QUOTE is still useful when you need to display (through PUT or TITLE) a sentence which includes a text enclosed within parentheses, while this texte is too long to appear on a single line.
In this case you might allocate this text on two consecutive lines : while the opening parenthesis lies on the first line, the closing parenthesis lies on the second.
The occurrence of a '(' after the '(' immediately following the %BQUOTE token seems to disturb %BQUOTE (see below, my example code).
On the other hand, the %QUOTE function works correctly, provided that a % sign is put before each isolated parenthesis.

```
DATA _NULL_; * %BQUOTE treats correctly a pair of parentheses, and an isolated closing parenthesis as well;
  FILE PRINT;
  %LET two_parentheses=%BQUOTE(... (text enclosed within parentheses) ....); 
  PUT "&two_parentheses"; 
  %LET closing_p_only=%BQUOTE(end of text enclosed within parentheses)...); 
  PUT "&closing_p_only"; 
RUN;

DATA _NULL_; * for opening parenthesis, %BQUOTE does not work ;
  FILE PRINT;
  %LET opening_p_only=%BQUOTE(... (beginning of text enclosed within parentheses); 
  PUT "&opening_p_only"; 
RUN;
```

- It sends nothing to the output window, no WARNING or ERROR message to the log window, and SAS no longer works.
  The following messages might be displayed if you submit now a correct portion of code:

  ```
  ERROR: Expected open parenthesis after macro function name not found.
  ERROR: Open code statement recursion detected.
  ```
- To recover, submit the following small (not magic, because we guess what SAS is waiting) chain:        ); RUN;
- my solution: substitute %QUOTE(...%(....) to %BQUOTE(.....(....);

```
DATA _NULL_;
  FILE PRINT;
  %LET opening_p_only=%QUOTE(... %(beginning of text enclosed within parentheses); 
  PUT "&opening_p_only"; 
RUN;
```

My tentative conclusion is that we should not forget the %QUOTE function as long as we are not aware of the way to use the %BQUOTE function to cope with an opening parenthesis.

But, maybe, I miss something about what %BQUOTE() is already able to deal with.

Comment: Your code examples are confusing becuase you have embedded %LET macro statements that will run before the data step is even compiled into the middle of data steps.  Move those statement before the DATA statement to make the order of execution clearer.

Comment: I have rewritten my code along your suggestion (increasing readability but  not changing my conclusion) . Unfortunately as I copy it below, I got the message: "Too long by 365 characters". Sorry!

Comment: In order to comply with your suggestion, I follow the advice "End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak:". But, adding 2 blank spaces at the end of each of my code lines results in increasing the number of characters in excess. Anyway, thanks for having edited the first version of my code (that I sent after having unsuccessfully try to indent, along the instructions of the Help page).

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. When I type into the edit window on this site just hitting the enter key inserts a line break.  In your answer above you have some long lines with two long SAS statements on one line.  It is possible some of the SAS code is confusing markdown processor that is displaying the text on this site?

Comment: Your example is faulty, because you're using `%QUOTE` for something you should be using `%STR` for.  If there is things in the static text to be masked, use `%STR`, as there is in your example.  `%BQUOTE` would mask things fine if it were an execution-time issue.

Comment: In the code below, I try to follow both pieces of advice: put the %LET statement before the data step (Tom's suggestion) and substitute %STR to %QUOTE (Joe's suggestion): and  I suppress the % sign which was placed before the opening parenthesis. But I get errors (whether the PUT statement uses, or dont use, double quotes).  Could you, please, write down the code you have in mind instead?                                                                                                                   %LET opening_p_only=%STR(... ();  DATA _NULL_;  FILE PRINT;   PUT "&opening_p_only";  RUN;

Comment: You need to add the preceding `%` in `%STR` just like you did in your example using `%QUOTE`.

Comment: Thanks! The following code does work: %LET opening=%STR(... %(); 
DATA _NULL_;
FILE PRINT;
PUT "&opening"; 
RUN;

Comment: A example of situation  (and corresponding SAS code) in which %BQUOTE is needed and treats correctly a text including an opening isolated parenthesis  will be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`%QUOTE` realistically has no purpose in modern SAS - `%BQUOTE` supersedes it for any typical usage.  The only difference, per [Summary of Macro Quoting Functions](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/p0pwrvnlcooi3tn0z3g1755ebcng.htm), is that `%BQUOTE` masks single unmatched quotes and parentheses automatically, while `%QUOTE` requires a `%` character to mask them.

In theory, if you wanted SAS to effectively crash when it encountered an umatched quotation mark, then `%QUOTE` would have some value - but that's really not a good idea, especially since SAS does not have robust `TRY-CATCH` methods; it would simply crash SAS.